# Swift: How do I link an action to a view inside of a tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uislider

Normally you can link a slider to an @IBAction using the storyboard, then anytime the slider is moved, that method is executed, but...

Let's say I have a slider inside a tableViewCell. Normally I can only access it by tag because it isn't the same slider as the one on the StoryBoard:

```
let slider = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as UISlider
```

And change or access it like this:

```
slider.value = lroundf(50)
```

But what if I want to link it to an @IBAction? What if I want it to do something when the slider is moved? How would I do this if it's inside a cell?

I noticed that there's a method called "didChange", but there is absolutely no documentation anywhere on how to use this method or if it does what it is I'm trying to do.

Comment: Are you using static or dynamic cells?

Comment: Dynamic cells, grouped. Each slider has its own section with a single cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderMoved:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)


func sliderMoved(slider: UISlider) {
    println("value: \(slider.value)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!! Perfect! I just tested it and it works. I'll mark it in 5 mins when I'm allowed. This answers so many other problems I've had with views in cells. Thanks!

Comment: Is there some way to send an object, such as the cell, along with it to the sliderMoved method?

Comment: No, this doesn't work. But you could get the cell otherwise, for example by subclassing UISlider and setting the cell as instance variable.